# как отсортировать такой список ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

Tags: java, android, listview, сортировка

Kак отсортировать такой список `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;`
получаю данные из сети, кусок кода

```
  protected String doInBackground(Object... args) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // получаем JSON строк с URL
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_product_detials, "GET", params);

            try {
                // Получаем SUCCESS тег для проверки статуса ответа сервера
                int success = 0;
                try {
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("mylog","success");
                    // продукт найден
                    // Получаем масив из Продуктов
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                    Log.d("mylog","TAG_PRODUCTS poluchen ");
                    // перебор всех продуктов
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Сохраняем каждый json елемент в переменную
                        String topic_id = c.getString(TOPIC_ID);
                        String forum_id = c.getString(FORUM_ID);
                        String author= c.getString(TOPIC_AUTHOR);
                        String str= c.getString(TOPIC_TITLE);

                        ///reg_X
                        String[] find = {"&", "q", "u","o","t",";"};
                        for (String temp : find) {
                            str = str.replace(temp, "");
                        }
                        ///end_reg_x
                        String topic_title = str;


                        // Создаем новый HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // добавляем каждый елемент в HashMap ключ => значение
                        map.put(TOPIC_ID, topic_id);
                        map.put(FORUM_ID, forum_id);
                        map.put(TOPIC_AUTHOR, author);
                        map.put(TOPIC_TITLE, topic_title);

                        // добавляем HashList в ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);

                    }
                } else {


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * После завершения фоновой задачи закрываем прогрес диалог
         **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // закрываем прогресс диалог после получение все продуктов
            Log.d("mylog","productlist="+productsList.toString());
            if(productsList.toArray().length==0){
                Log.d("mylog","productlist=null");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"В данной ветке нет активных тем",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               // FragmentTransaction ftrans=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(TAG);
               // ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fragmentForumGroup);
               // ftrans.commit();
            }
else{   
            /**
             * Обновляем распарсенные JSON данные в ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(

                    getActivity(), productsList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TOPIC_ID,
                    FORUM_ID, TOPIC_TITLE,TOPIC_AUTHOR},
                    new int[]{R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.desc,R.id.author});

                Log.d("prefLog","array prodlist"+adapter.toString());
            // обновляем listview

              lv.setAdapter(adapter);}
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }
```

на выходе получаю listView как можно отсортировать список по дате , алфавиту пробывал через collection скормить ему адаптер productsList или hashmap

Comment: По дате? Не вижу среди ключей отображения ничего похоже на дату.

Comment: ну по любому из ключей к примеру по автору или topic_title по алфавиту

Comment: А зачем из одного `Map` (JSONObject по сути тоже Map) создавать другой? Работайте с JSONObject, может так проще будет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Comparator<Map<String, String>> mapComparator = new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
    public int compare(Map<String, String> a, Map<String, String> b) {
        String aTitle = a.get(TOPIC_TITLE);
        String bTitle = b.get(TOPIC_TITLE);

        if(aTitle == null && bTitle == null)
            return 0;
        if(aTitle != null && bTitle == null)
            return -1;
        if(aTitle == null && bTitle != null)
            return 1;
        return aTitle.compareTo(bTitle);
    }
};
Collections.sort(productsList, mapComparator);
```

Ещё проще, если код пишется для Android 7

```
Comparator<String> nullSafeStringComparator = Comparator.nullsLast(String::compareToIgnoreCase);
Collections.sort(productsList, (a, b) -> {
    return nullSafeStringComparator.compare(a.get("title"), b.get("title"));
});
```